# Does this problem contradict the uniqueness theorem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have a first order second degree ODE , and we solved it for y' . Then we will get two solutions : one solution using the positive square root and another one using the negative square root . 
So do first order second degree ODE contradict always the uniqueness theorem at all points (x,y) ? 
For example the following ODE:
$$x^2y^2y'^2-(x^2+y^2)y'+1=0$$
I got from positive square root , this solution : 
$$x=\frac{y^3}{3}+c_1$$
From negative square root , we obtain this solution:
$$y=\frac{x^3}{3}+c_2$$
OR we have to look to the solution as one equation :
$$(x-\frac{y^3}{3}-c_1)(y-\frac{x^3}{3}-c_2)=0$$
So this does not contradict the uniqueness theorem ? and if it contradicts how to know which points have more than one solution ?

Comment: You should find a solution of the form $y=y(x)$.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean ? I should find a solution in the form of y as function of x , for what thing to happen ?